# Is it possible to setup a toggle button when includeNativeBool is set to false?

Tags: codenameone

According to the Developer Guide, to make a toggle button I should run `setToggle(true)` on a `CheckBox`. I couldn't get that to work at first, so I tried on a new theme and it worked just fine. After some experimentation I found that this only happens when `includeNativeBool` constant is set to false.

When I press the button, it changes to the pressed state, but when I release it, it changes back to the unselected/selected state. However, when I press it a second time, it doesn't change to the pressed state at all (maybe because it's internally "checked" already), and when I release it nothing happens. When I press it a third time, it behaves like the first, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not removing the `includeNativeBool`, you will run into basic complexities.

The toggle button works just as well without `includeNativeBool` but the the styles for `ToggleButton` won't be in the theme. Assuming you styled `Button` just use `setUIID("Button");`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I had already tried both styling ToggleButton or using different UIIDs (including Button) before and I still can't get it to work. However I think I narrowed down the problem. It seems that when I release the toggle button, the state changes from pressed to the selected state, and since there's no such thing as a selected+pressed style and selected+unpressed style, then the toggle button will always look one way or another when selected, regardless of whether it's "checked" or not.